# Including javascript globally using webpack

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using webpack and Vuejs.  I have several components in my application, and I want to use `momentjs` globally.  Everything I've tried so far doesn't seem to work and throws and `Undefined` error in console.  Is there a way to get set `moment.js` globally available to all components from `main.js` using webpack?

These are the things I've tried (in `main.js`):

```
import moment from 'moment';

Vue.prototype.$moment = moment;
```

In a component I try to access it via `this.$moment` but get an undefined error.

I also tried:

```
import moment from 'moment';

Object.definePrototype(Vue.prototype, '$moment', { value: moment });
```

I also tried to access it via `this.$moment`, but get the same `undefined` error on `this.$moment`.

Am I missing a step or doing something wrong to include a javascript file globally to all components using webpack?

Thanks again for the help!

**UPDATES**

By the way, `momentjs` works fine if I import it in every component I want to use it in (as follows, however, this is what I'm trying to avoid):

```
import moment from 'moment';

...

let today_date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

**UPDATES 2***

This is the exact error (with using `this.`):

```
Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$moment' of undefined"
```

This is error (without using `this.`):

```
Error in render function: "ReferenceError: $moment is not defined"
```

Moment is added via `dependencies` in `package.json`:

```
...
"babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"css-loader": "^0.28.5",
"es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
...
```

Code usage within a component:

```
...
filters: {
    getYear(date) {
      return this.$moment(date).format('YYYY');
    },
    getMonth(date) {
      return this.$moment(date).format('MMM');
    },
    getDay(date) {
      return this.$moment(date).format('D');
    },
 },
 ...
```

Comment: This should be working. You've definitely installed moment? What exact error are you getting? Can you share an example of where you are trying to access `this.$moment`?

Comment: If I include moment in every component using import, it works fine.  But setting it up globally isn't working.

Comment: I'm following you there. But, what exact error are you getting? And can you share an example of where you are trying to access `this.$moment`?

Comment: See updates above.

Comment: So that error means that `this` is undefined, not `$moment`. Can you show the rest of the component? Are you using Vue v1 or v2?

Comment: I am using Vue 2.  If I include this in the code, I get one error.  If I don't include this in the code I get different error (see updates with both errors now).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155845/discussion-between-thanksd-and-sean).